# How can I extend my wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a wireless network in my house, but it doesn't extend to all the rooms in my house. I was wondering if I could take an Ethernet cable from my current modem/router combination unit, and connect it to another router at the other end of the house, but have only one wireless network that was seamless.

If this is possible, can I have some pointers on how I could set this up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extend my wifi coverage?](http://superuser.com/questions/188575/how-can-i-extend-my-wifi-coverage)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's possible. You are looking for a [Wireless access point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point).

> In computer networking, a wireless
>   access point (WAP) is a device that
>   allows wireless devices to connect to
>   a wired network using Wi-Fi, Bluetooth
>   or related standards. The WAP usually
>   connects to a router (via a wired
>   network), and can relay data between
>   the wireless devices (such as
>   computers or printers) and wired
>   devices on the network.

Comment: How about the issue of having devices seamlessly change access points when it moves from one location to another?

Comment: If your device knows the AP's it should automatically connect to an available one if it loses connection to another one.

Comment: Right, but what about choosing a new one, when the old one has a weak signal. And can both my access points have the same signal?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. For the new wireless router, just make sure you disable the `DHCP server`. Configure the `SSID` to be the same as your current modem/router and change the `channel` to something else as well.